# Python Pandas make calculation in single cell

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, loops

I have a TYPE column
and a VOLUME column
What I'm looking to do if first check if TYPE column == 'var1'

If so I would like to make a calculation in the VOLUME column.

So far I have something like this:

```
data.loc[data['TYPE'] == 'var1', ['VOLUME']] * 2
data.loc[data['TYPE'] == 'var1', ['VOLUME']] * 4
```

This seems to set the entire column that meets the condition to the last variable. So I end up with just two values.

Out:

```
4
4
4
4
8
8
8
```

Another option:

```
data['VOLUME'] = data.loc[data['TYPE'] == 'var1', ['VOLUME']] * 2
```

This works for the first condition but show NaN for the second condition
Then when I run:

```
data['VOLUME'] = data.loc[data['TYPE'] == 'var2', ['VOLUME']] * 4
```

The whole column show as NaN.

Comment: Please add a sample of the input data, and a sample of what you want the output to look like, to make a [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider a simple example which demonstrates what is happening.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2, 3]})
df

   A
0  1
1  2
2  3
```

Now, only values below 2 in column "A" are to be modified. So, try something like

```
df.loc[df.A < 2, 'A'] * 2

0    2
Name: A, dtype: int64
```

This series only has 1 row at index 0. If you try assigning this back, the implicit assumption is that the other index values are to be reset to NaN.

```
df.assign(A=df.loc[df.A < 2, 'A'] * 2)

     A
0  2.0
1  NaN
2  NaN
```

---

What we want to do is to modify *only* the rows we're interested in. This is best done with the in-place modification arithmetic operator `*=`:

```
df.loc[df.A < 2, 'A'] *= 2
```

In your case, it is

```
data.loc[data['TYPE'] == 'var1', 'VOLUME'] *= 2
```

Answer (score 1):

You are really close. The problem is in how you are storing the result. This should work:

```
 data.loc[data['TYPE'] == 'var1', ['VOLUME']] = data['VOLUME'] * 2
```

Comment: You will calculate the multiplication for the entire column and then proceed to discard the entries you don't need. Good, but not as good as it could be (check out the other answers).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `*=` with loc:

```
In [11]: df = pd.DataFrame([[1], [2]], columns=["A"])

In [12]: df
Out[12]:
   A
0  1
1  2

In [13]: df.loc[df.A == 1, "A"] *= 3

In [14]: df
Out[14]:
   A
0  3
1  2
```